# Merge multiple SVG elements into one SVG and download it with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a logo creator in my app.

User has to type smthn in input field (for example "TESTING") and then it renders in preview block.
[image: User has to type smthn in input field (for example "TESTING") and then it renders in preview block]

Every letter in preview is the `svg` element:

*(Each letter can be a glyph letter or regular letter, it means that there are 2 different fonts)*

```js
const C = ({ glyph }) => {
    if (!glyph) {
        return (
            <svg width="93" height="132" viewBox="0 0 93 132" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                    d="M75 41.76L87.6 34.92C82.2 21.6 67.2 10.8 49.08 10.8C19.92 10.8 4.8 30.12 4.8 54C4.8 77.88 19.2 97.2 49.08 97.2C67.2 97.2 82.2 86.4 87.6 73.08L75 66.12C71.04 75.72 61.92 84 48.48 84C30.72 84 19.68 71.76 19.68 54C19.68 36.24 30.72 24 48.48 24C61.92 24 71.04 32.28 75 41.76Z"
                    fill="currentColor"
                />
            </svg>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <svg width="96" height="132" viewBox="0 0 96 132" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                    d="M20.4 51.24H33.6C33.6 31.92 42.24 24 54.36 24C64.92 24 72.36 29.16 76.2 40.56L88.8 33.6C83.4 19.2 71.64 10.8 54.48 10.8C32.04 10.8 18.72 25.08 18.72 51.24H4.8C4.8 80.52 24.48 97.08 49.8 97.08C70.68 97.08 83.04 85.8 89.16 74.04L77.64 67.44C71.88 77.16 64.2 83.64 50.4 83.64C33.12 83.64 21.12 71.16 20.4 51.24Z"
                    fill="currentColor"
                />
            </svg>
        );
    }
};
```

I change glyph state by clicking on letter (this is a hover view):

[image]

How it looks in devtools:
[image: How it looks in devtools:]

### **What i expect:**

**On download click:**

I need to download this logo ("TESTING") as `.svg` file.

```js
const svgHtml = Array.from(logoRef.current.querySelectorAll('span'))
            .map((el) => el.innerHTML)
            .join('\n');

const svg = `
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        ${svgHtml}
    </svg>
`;

const blob = new Blob([svg], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
createDownloadLink(blob, `${inputText}.svg`);
```

### **Actual behavior:**

All letters have no relative positioning as in preview:
[image: Actual behavior]

Do you have any ideas how can i do this?

**Or maybe there is a better solution you can purpose?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: A way of doing it: put all the letters as symbols in the <defs> of an svg element `<symbol viewBox="0 0 87 132" ...`. Give the symbol an id. In order to display the letter usa a `<use href="#theID">` element with the desired size (width="87" height="132") and position (x and y attributes)

Comment: It might be easier to convert your letter svgs to a proper .woff or .ttf font file (e.g using fontello or icomoon app) and generate the combined text path via [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js). See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/XWZGVbZ)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate **x offset** values for each letter svg before merging them, since they have no idea how they are positioned in the HTML DOM context (i.e as children of `<span>` elements).

This offset value would be incremented by the `viewBox` width
(3. viewBox argument: viewBox="0 0 93 132" => width=93):

#### JavaScript example

```js
let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
let svgMarkup = '';
let xOffset = 0;
let viewBoxHeight = 132;
let letterSpacing = 5;
spans.forEach((span,i)=>{
  let svg = span.querySelector('svg');
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(span)
  let color = style.color;
  let viewBox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' ');
  let width = +viewBox[2];
  let glyph = svg.querySelector('path');
  // clone path to apply offset
  let glyphCloned = glyph.cloneNode(true);
  // apply x offset by translate()
  glyphCloned.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${xOffset} 0)`);
  glyphCloned.style.color=color;
  let glyphMarkup = glyphCloned.outerHTML;
  glyphCloned.remove();
  svgMarkup+=glyphMarkup;
  // increment offset for next letter
  xOffset += i==spans.length-1 ? width : width+letterSpacing;
})

let svgCombined = `
<svg id="combined" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${xOffset}" height="${viewBoxHeight}" viewBox="0 0 ${xOffset} ${viewBoxHeight}">
  ${svgMarkup} 
</svg>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', svgCombined);
```

```css
svg{
  height:10em;
  width:auto;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}


.blue{
  color:blue
}
```

```html
<span><svg width="93" height="132" viewBox="0 0 93 132" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M75 41.76L87.6 34.92C82.2 21.6 67.2 10.8 49.08 10.8C19.92 10.8 4.8 30.12 4.8 54C4.8 77.88 19.2 97.2 49.08 97.2C67.2 97.2 82.2 86.4 87.6 73.08L75 66.12C71.04 75.72 61.92 84 48.48 84C30.72 84 19.68 71.76 19.68 54C19.68 36.24 30.72 24 48.48 24C61.92 24 71.04 32.28 75 41.76Z" fill="currentColor" />
  </svg>
</span>
<span class="blue">
  <svg width="96" height="132" viewBox="0 0 96 132" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20.4 51.24H33.6C33.6 31.92 42.24 24 54.36 24C64.92 24 72.36 29.16 76.2 40.56L88.8 33.6C83.4 19.2 71.64 10.8 54.48 10.8C32.04 10.8 18.72 25.08 18.72 51.24H4.8C4.8 80.52 24.48 97.08 49.8 97.08C70.68 97.08 83.04 85.8 89.16 74.04L77.64 67.44C71.88 77.16 64.2 83.64 50.4 83.64C33.12 83.64 21.12 71.16 20.4 51.24Z" fill="currentColor" />
  </svg>
</span>
<span><svg width="93" height="132" viewBox="0 0 93 132" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M75 41.76L87.6 34.92C82.2 21.6 67.2 10.8 49.08 10.8C19.92 10.8 4.8 30.12 4.8 54C4.8 77.88 19.2 97.2 49.08 97.2C67.2 97.2 82.2 86.4 87.6 73.08L75 66.12C71.04 75.72 61.92 84 48.48 84C30.72 84 19.68 71.76 19.68 54C19.68 36.24 30.72 24 48.48 24C61.92 24 71.04 32.28 75 41.76Z" fill="currentColor" />
  </svg>
</span>


<p>Combined Svg</p>
```

The example above will also select only the `<path>` elements instead of their parent `<svg>`s.
In fact, you could also set an offset via `x` attribute.
However, a lot of **graphic applications struggle with nested svgs** - so copying only paths is usually a more robust solution for standalone svgs.

Besides, we're adding a `viewBox` based to the total width and height of all combined letter svgs.